# How can I disallow WebView to open links on the browser in WinRT( target=_blank links )?

Tags: c#, webview, windows-runtime, target

I have a WebView on my app and I can't change the html file("target=_blank" link types). But some links on the page makes my app open them on the system browser. How can I disallow this action?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the NavigationCompleted event handler run this script:

```
webView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new[]
            {
                @"(function()
                {
                    var hyperlinks = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
                    for(var i = 0; i < hyperlinks.length; i++)
                    {
                        if(hyperlinks[i].getAttribute('target') != null)
                        {
                            hyperlinks[i].setAttribute('target', '_self');
                        }
                    }
                })()"
            });
```

Comment: Hey! Great buddy! thanks it worked. just added await keywork before webView and make the event async, it worked perfect.

Answer (score 10):

On Windows 10, you can use `WebView.NewWindowRequested`:

```
private void WebView1_NewWindowRequested(
    WebView sender,
    WebViewNewWindowRequestedEventArgs args)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(args.Uri);
    args.Handled = true; // Prevent the browser from being launched.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a navigation starting event.  It have a cancel property that can be used to cancel the navigation.  Maybe this will work for you?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.navigationstarting

Comment: This event is only available for Windows 8.1 Preview.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I looked at the WebView control just now and couldnt see any hooks.  Maybe you could do something hacky?  You just want to disable the links?  Maybe can load the web page in a iframe and have some javascript that will disable all the links.  Loop through the achors on the page and set their onclicks to return false.  The WebView has this InvokeScript method but it looks like is just for invoking an existing function on the page and you cannot just inject any code.  Should be straight forward though to build up some html and use the NavigateToString method

Comment: Starting event is only called when you're navigating inside WebView. Any link that requests a new window won't be notified, AFAIK

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled on this myself recently, and I want to add that even though [user2269867's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27145407/2279177) answer is a viable solution, it might not work in certain situations.

For example, system browser will not only open if user click a link with target="_blank" attribute, but also if window.open() function called in javascript. Moreover, even removing all 'target' attributes won't work if a page loading some content dynamically and changing DOM after your script is already finished executing.

To solve all problems above, you need to override window.open function and also check for 'target' attribute not once, but every time user click something. Here is script that covers those cases:

```
function selfOrParentHasAttribute(e, attributeName) {
    var el = e.srcElement || e.target;

    if (el.hasAttribute(attributeName)) {
        return el;
    }
    else {
        while (el = el.parentNode) {
            if (el.hasAttribute(attributeName)) {
                return el;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}

var targetAttributeName = "target";

document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    var el = selfOrParentHasAttribute(e, targetAttributeName);

    if (el) {
        if ((el.getAttribute(targetAttributeName) == "_blank") ||
            (el.getAttribute(targetAttributeName) == "_new"))
        {
             el.removeAttribute(targetAttributeName);
        }
}
});


window.open = function () {
    return function (url) {
        window.location.href = url;
    };
}(window.open);
```

My js skills aren't ideal, so feel free to modify.
Also don't forget that, as kiewic [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38138656/2279177), for Windows 10 there is WebView.NewWindowRequested event which solves this issue more natural.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to show the page and not allow any action to be done on that page I would look into WebViewBrush. The WebViewBrush will basically screenshot the website and the users will not be able to use any links or anything else on that page, it will turn into a read-only page. I believe this is what you are asking for.

More info on WebViewBrush can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webviewbrush

Comment: No, the user can navigate on the site as he wish. The problem is that the site has some links to open on another tab, and that cause the app to call the browser. I need to stop it from calling the browser without changing the html.

Answer (score 0):

If you can edit HTML of the page and NavigateToString(), then add <base target='_blank'/> in the <head>

Comment: After testing this solution I've seen that sometimes you also disable CSS and external files that must be processed with the main web content.